# Plotting multiple columns using matplotlib: KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of data from 7 columns that I would like to plot in order to compare results.
Please see below a sample of data:

```
Date Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4 ...
2020-03-24 0 0 0 0 ...
2020-03-25 0 1 20 0 ...
2020-03-26 1 3 23 6 ...
...
```

Please notice that the name columns are generic (I have different names for them).

I have tried to plot them as follows:

```
df['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6','Num7'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

but I got this error:

```
KeyError: ('Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6','Num7')
```

What I would like to have is multiple lines, one for each column, through time, or a stacked plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input df:

```
Date            Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4
0   2020-03-24  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2020-03-25  0.0 1.0 20.0 0.0
2   2020-03-26  1.0 3.0 23.0 6.0
```

Then:

```
df.index = df.Date
df.drop(["Date"],  axis=1, inplace=True)
df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Remove `stacked=True` if you don't want a stacked bar plot.

Comment: I got this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'`. Do you know why?

Comment: It could be that Date is the index of your dataframe and is not one of the column. You can check it if you print `df.index`

Comment: This is the output: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=142, step=1)
In [ ]:`

Comment: Ok It seems like `Date` is then part of the columns. Check it with `df.columns` and see whether Date is there please. If it is there then you can set the index in this way: `df.index=df["Date"]`

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting error: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: I tried to run my code with the dataframe you put in the question and it works fine. Are you sure that the format of your dataframe is like the one you posted above in the question?

Comment: I found an error in my dataset. Trying df.columns I got  `Index(['Date;Num1;Num2;Num3;Num4;Num5;Num6;Num7'], dtype='object')
In [21]:` . I will try to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use:

```
df.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got this error using your code: `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

Comment: Sure - make sure that your columns are formatted:

`df = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.astype(float)`

Those edits should work.

Comment: I got this other error: TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype float64

Comment: Oh okay, so the date isn't your index. So after you've converted it to datetime, set it as the index using:
`df = df.set_index("Date")`